# Remote_app_id does not match stored id only on jellybean

Tags: android, facebook, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I think my "Key Hash" which I generated using "keytool" was correct because it works on lower versions on android. Any reason why this error is seen only on Jellybean??

Comment: Did you have a version on that phone that was signed with a debug key?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same version on both the phones